# object state after submit button in react

Tags: reactjs

I have here the logic of percent calculating for a progress bar. All the objects state are rendered and checked from a form. Everything works fine, but the percent state doesn't update with pe pressing of submit form button, only when I refresh the page. How can I do that?

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
    this.therapist = this.props.userDetails;
    this.autheHeaders = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.therapist.token}`,
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    };

    const newState = {
        email: this.therapist.email || "",
        firstName: this.therapist.firstName || "",
        lastName: this.therapist.lastName || "",
        website: this.therapist.website || "",
        bio: this.therapist.bio || "",
        phone: this.therapist.phone || "",
        title: this.therapist.title || "",
        profileImageName: this.therapist.profileImageName,


    };
    this.setState(() => newState);
    if (this.therapist.phone) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            percent: prevState.percent + 16
        }));
    }
    if ((this.therapist.bio)
    ) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            percent: prevState.percent + 16
        }));
    }
    if (this.therapist.title) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            percent: prevState.percent + 16
        }));
    }
    if (this.therapist.profileImageName) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            percent: prevState.percent + 16
        }));
    }
    if (this.therapist.website) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            percent: prevState.percent + 16
        }));
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        percent: prevState.percent
    }));
};
```

submit form code:
handleSubmit is rendered onPress button

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState(
        {
            errors: [],
            errorMessage: "",
            pageLoading: true,
        },
        () => {
            if (!this.validateForm()) return;

            if (!this.state.profileImgFile) {
                this.updateProfileData()
                return
            }

            this.uploadProfilePhoto().then( res => {
                let { url: fileName } = res.data
                this.updateProfileData(fileName)
                window.location.reload();
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
        }
    );
};

updateProfileData = (profileImageName = null) => {
    console.log("",this.state.percent)

    const rConfig = {
        body: {
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            email: this.state.email,
            website: this.state.website,
            phone: this.state.phone,
            title: this.state.title,
            bio: this.state.bio,
            profileImageName
        },
        headers: this.autheHeaders,
        resource: this.submitUrl,
        userDetails: this.props.userDetails,
        percent: this.state.percent,
    };
    this.props.actions.reqUpdateTherapistProfile(rConfig);
}
```

Comment: `componentDidMount()` only executes when the DOM node is being mounted. Try using a different lifecycle method like [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the progress inside of the render function and you should do that based on the object from `this.props.userDetails` directly, instead of assigning it to the `this.therapist` property.

```js
render = () => {
    // ...
    const therapist = this.props.userDetails;
    let progress = 0;

    if (therapist.phone) progress += 16;
    // ...

    return (
        <div>
            { progress }
        </div>
    );
}
```